# Key error in pandas groupby (not caused by whitespace or index)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, keyerror

Currently in the process of migrating some code from pyspark to pandas.  I'm trying to do aggregate functions to a pandas dataframe and I keep getting a groupby error.  The relevant part is

```
    tmp_cost = df[['veh_ident_nbr','svc_labr_oprtn_cd','svc_labr_oprtn_desc','job_card_dt', 'rpt_tot_globl_amount']]\
                    .drop_duplicates('rpt_tot_globl_amount').drop(columns = ['veh_ident_nbr', 'job_card_dt'])
    
    tmp_agg_cost = tmp_cost.groupby(['svc_labr_oprtn_cd', 'svc_labr_oprtn_desc'])
```

This should be a simple grouping, exactly like even the examples on the online Pandas documentation, but I keep getting a key error on svc_labr_oprtn_desc (never on svc_labr_oprtn_cd).  I've checked that there's no hidden whitespace and I've tried reset_index in case that was the problem, but I get the same error no matter what I try.  I can't find anyone getting this error where the problem isn't caused by whitspace, indexes, or messing up the column name.  What else could be causing this?

Comment: Why are you including columns when creating the df and then just dropping them?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Add sample original contents of `df`.